# Entity Framwork Code First Migrations

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, code-first

If I run the following code in Package Manager Console:

```
-Update-Database -Force
```

Apart from the Seed method that runs some default data to the tables, I thought also that all of the tables was cleaned before, but this seems to be incorrect!?

EDIT:

I still find it strange why the tables in the database isn't droped when I run the -update-database -force, should they not do that? And why does the data that are added with the Seed method keep adding the data every time I run -update-database. Once again, should not the prevoius added data be overwritten? When I read the text below from [ASP.NET](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/migrations-and-deployment-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application) this link and on other sources It seems like it should be possible to seed with new data and old data or tables should be dropped!? Have I missunderstood this or am I doing something wrong?

```
 You have configured the Entity Framework to automatically drop and
 re-create the database each time you change the data model. When you
 add, remove, or change entity classes or change your DbContext class,
 the next time you run the application it automatically deletes your 
 existing database, creates a new one that matches the model, and seeds
 it with test data.
```

Comment: If you delete the database you should have an initializer set to create a new one

Comment: @Ortund I'm new to ASP.NET MVC and in previous project during studies, I remember that I have just deleted the DB and then typed some commands or it was created by Visual Studio, but I can be wrong? What du you mean with initializer?

Comment: I'll explain in an answer but you don't need to accept it unless it works

Answer (score 2):

Using Entity Framework Code First you can have your MVC project delete and recreate your database when it runs by using [Database Initializers](http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/article.php/c19999/Understanding-Database-Initializers-in-Entity-Framework-Code-First.htm).

```
//Global.asax.cs
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);

        // instanciate your DbContext class
        OrtundEntities db = new OrtundEntities();
        db.Database.Initialize(true); // this calls your chosen initializer
        db.Seed();
    }

// OrtundEntities
    public OrtundEntities()
        : base("DefaultConnection")
    {
        Database.SetInitializer<OrtundEntities>(DropCreateDatabaseAlways);
    }
```

This will always drop and create the database when you run the MVC website (I believe whenever a user visits it as well so only use `DropCreateDatabaseAlways` for testing purposes).

Alternatively, if there's just one or two tables you want to empty, the following will do just fine in your controller. This has the benefit of keeping all other data in tact and only emptying the tables that you want emptied.

```
    public JsonResult ClearAll()
    {
        try
        {
            // clears the Receipts and Rewards tables
            db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("truncate table Receipts");
            db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("truncate table Rewards");

            return Json(true, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return Json(ex.Message, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
    }
```

**EDIT**

I forgot to mention that if the tables you truncate with the above function have relational data that other tables rely on then any query to those tables are likely going to cause errors.